# how to force 3 dots in actionBar menu?

Tags: java, android, menu, android-actionbar

I have the following menu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

            <item
        android:id="@+id/action_totalCerdit"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="-100"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/actions_saved"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_full_text"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_full_list"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_saved_text"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_favorites_list"/>

        <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/log_out"/>
</menu>
```

When deploying on Samsung Note2 The action Bar shows all items that don't have `android:showAsAction="never"`. The ones with that attributes are show when pressing  samsung built-in left bottom menu button.

When deploring on Nexus4 I see all items with `android:showAsAction="never"` as sub menus of "3 dots" item.

how can I make these 3 dots appear and behave in note2 the same as in nexus4?

Comment: are you using support library?

Comment: no. btw  android:minSdkVersion="14"

Answer (score 1):

In [Compatibility Definition Document](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf), Google said that Android 4.4+ device **SHOULD NOT implement a dedicated physical button for the Menu function**. So later device would be fine.

But it seems like NoteII makes a built in menu button for Overflow in Action bar (3 dots menu button). If you really want to do it on NoteII, there is an old hack that I found:

```
try {
 ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
 Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");

 if (menuKeyField != null) {
 menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
 menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
 }
} catch (Exception e) {
// presumably, not relevant
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
```

Add this to all your `Activity` classes. Now you will see the same thing on both the Note 2 and the Nexus 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement this method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.yourfile.xml, menu);
    return true;
}
```